# Import multiple files in pandas

Tags: pandas, import

I am trying to import multiple files in pandas. I have created 3 files in the folder
['File1.xlsx', 'File2.xlsx', 'File3.xlsx'] as read by files = os.listdir(cwd)

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath(r'C:\Users\abc\OneDrive\Import Multiple files') 
files = os.listdir(cwd)  
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(file), ignore_index=True) 
df.head() 
# df.to_excel('total_sales.xlsx')

print (files)
```

Upon running the code, I am getting the error (even though the file does exist in the folder)

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'File1.xlsx'**

Ideally, I want a code where I define a list of files in a LIST and then read the files through the loop using the path and the file LIST.

Comment: the issue is that listdir just gives the file names, not the full path. you can use this instead `files = [os.path.join(cwd,path) for path in os.listdir(cwd) if path.endswith('.xlsx')]`

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work

```
import os
import pandas as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath(r'C:\Users\abc\OneDrive\Import Multiple files') 
paths = [os.path.join(cwd,path) for path in os.listdir(cwd) if path.endswith('.xlsx')]
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(path,ignore_index=True) for path in paths)
df.head()
```

The idea is to get a list of full paths and then read them all in and concatenate them into a single dataframe on the next line

Comment: Thanks. What about if I want to pick specific files? can I put names fo the files some where?